# swap function when swapped object don't implement move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm reading about move semantics in c++ and encountered the following example as motivation:

```
template<class T> 
void swap(T& a, T& b) 
{ 
  T tmp(std::move(a));
  a = std::move(b); 
  b = std::move(tmp);
}
```

It said here that if T doesn't implement move semantics (in copy constructor and assignment operator), then swap will behave as "normal" swap:

```
template<class T>
void swap(T& a, T& b) 
{ 
  T tmp(a);
  a = b; 
  b = tmp; 
}
```

Why is that true? It's said [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_03.html) (last paragraph) that because `std::move(b)` is rvalue, we can't call the assignment operator with signature `Type& operator=(Type&)` when doing `a = std::move(b);`.

Comment: That's why you should use `Type& operator=(const Type&)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that an rvalue reference (`T&&`) can bind only to rvalues.
And a non-const lvalue reference (`T&`) can bind only to lvalues. But there is always the possibility to use `const T&`, which for historical reasons can bind to both rvalues and lvalues.

This is why you can pass a string literal to `const std::string&`.